# ERROR Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core

Tags: android, reactjs, iphone, react-native, sdk

I was trying to Upgrade my Expo SDK 46 to 48 - following the steps on Midium- https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231 but after following the upgrading commands, I started getting *ERROR  Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core*

Does anyone know how to fix this Error?
Thank you for your help in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGF7S.jpg)

This is the Error message that I am getting.

Comment: instead importing AsyncStorage from 'react-native' install and import it from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Naveed above in comment. You most likely have an import in one of your js/ts files causing the error since AsyncStorage is no longer in React-Native.

This import is **wrong**:
`import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'`

Make sure you have @react-native-async-storage/async-storage installed by following instructions here: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

Then change all imports from:

`import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'`

to

`import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using redux-offline, after digging through my node_modules I found that this package is using the deprecated AsyncStorage usage.

If you find a library in node modules is an offender it may be as simple as upgrading it, or in the case of redux-offline, patching it.